# Approaches for Database model with multiple junctions

Tags: django, database, database-design

I work with the python Django Framework and try to build a website. I want to achieve a good performance for the case described below and search for a good database/model design. Since this is a database-relating question in my eyes, I wrote about columns and tables. In Django I would replace them with the respective models and fields.

I have a model with a `user` and a `profile` table. `user` contains the primary user data like username and email. `profile` contains all other profile details like name, birthdate, favorite color and so on. `profile` has also some dependent tables like e.g. `custom_fields`, where users can add custom fields to their profile.

One user has exactly one profile that he owns. Every contact can see the users profile. I need to store the profile owner with the profile.

If a user (A) views the profile of another user (B) and misses some information, A can add this information into the profile of B. That changes are not visible for anyone but the creator A. That means I need to store the editor (A) and the target (B) together with the profile.

I thought about how to design this and found three approaches:

1. Copy the table `profile` (containing only the users own profile) into `edited_profile` (containing all edits), add a column `editor` for the user who does the edit and manage both tables. That means that I also have to copy all tables that depend on `profile` or need a layer of junction tables between `profile` and the dependent tables. Also, if I ever want to improve or extend the model, I will always have to watch to keep both tables consistent. This seems to be not the best solution in my eyes.
2. Add columns `user` and `editor` into `profile`. The users own profile is identified by `editor is NULL`. If I need a profile for something else (e.g. a group), I need to add respective columns to the `profile` table to refer to it. That may include a lot of changes in the SQL queries because I may need to filter for the new columns, too.
3. Add a column `profile_id` into `profile` and create some junction tables:

   - `user_profile (fk_user_id -> user_id, fk_profile_id -> profile_id)` and
   - `edited_profile (fk_user_id -> user_id, fk_editor_id -> user_id, fk_profile_id -> profile_id)`.

   If I need a profile for something else (e.g. a group), I need to add respective junction tables.

I want to have a good database design with performant look ups. Usually I need the users own profile alone or together with the edits that another user has applied. Which one of the approaches is the best regarding lookup/update performance and maintenance? Is there another better design that I have missed?

Thank you for your help!